# Advertising Query on Website

Tags: advertising

There is a site: www.freewebsitereport.org which reports services focused on estimating website approximate advertising revenue. But sometimes when I enter any website for its info, it shows ESTIMATED AD REVENUE: some value, even though when I open that site, I find no ads on it. Are there some other ways for advertisement?

Eg. check out: www.thefancy.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if it just estimates the ad revenue, you don't need to have any ads on the website. It probably takes into account things like:

- Backlinks
- Alexa rank
- Keywords
- Estimated search engine position
- Domain name history

In other words it tries to estimate the traffic that website can potentially generate, and from that it derives the potential revenue.

I didn't try that service, but in my opinion there types of service's aren't very accurate.

EDIT:

Yes advertising is the only way you can make money of a website. Unless of course you choose to charge people directly. But then you need to create product/service/content that people would be willing to pay for.

Comment: Thanks galdikas.
But is there other ways a site can earn instead of publishing ads?

Comment: yes, a major way that sites like uswitch.com earn is by affiliate links, they provide you with the service, ie. price comparison and when you click the provider uswitch will get a commision on sale.

Comment: how is buysellads.com?

Comment: sam is right about the affiliate links, but really they are means of advertisement as well.

buyselladds is one of the bigger ad exchanges, never used it, but i think it would be one of the better ones.

Comment: I also checked quora.com, don't found even a single ad on their website, so how does they generate revenue?

Comment: I dont't think they actually make any money. here is link about quora discussion about it:

[link](http://www.quora.com/Quora-company/How-does-Quora-make-money-11)